# Configurar o hibernate.cfg.xml com o DataSource configurado no Wildfly 10

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, wildfly

Estou tentando configurar meu hibernate para que reconheça a conexão configurado no Wildfly, já testei a conexão no painel do wildfly, ta 100% funcional. O problema agora é fazer a aplicação que utiliza hibernate visualizar o DS.

Answer (score -1):

Basta adicionar a seguinte configuração em seu arquivo **persistence.xmm**

```
<persistence-unit name="bell-adm" >

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <!-- jta-data-source deve conter o mesmo nome definido em datasource jndi-name no arquivos standalone.xml -->
    <jta-data-source>java:/BellAdmDS</jta-data-source>

    <!-- Entidades -->
    <class>br.com.belladm.model.orm.Usuario</class>
    <class>br.com.belladm.model.orm.Empresa</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Segue Exemplo: https://gist.github.com/marcelo-michels/cc250feb57e5d850f4d06c6f1a373a59#file-persistence-xml